# Setting maximum http connections for Apache fluent executor

Tags: connection, apache-httpcomponents, apache-fluent-api

Apache fluent API allows simple one-line http calls like:

```
String content = Request.Get(url).execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Which is executed by a [...fluent.Executor](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor.html), whose javadoc says:

> A PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with maximum 100 connections per route and a total maximum of 200 connections is used internally

I would like to change the maximum connection parameters to be used for a specific call, but I can't find a way to access the connection manager used by the above code. I have tried:

```
Executor.newInstance().execute(Request.Get("")).returnContent().asString();
```

but there is no way to change these parameters on the `Executor` returned by `Executor.newInstance()`.

Is there is way to use the fluent API but with custom maximum connection values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can bind an instance of the fluent executor to an arbitrary HttpClient instance

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(15);
Executor.newInstance(client).execute(Request.Get("/")).discardContent();
```